# JS - Check if element exist in loop

Tags: javascript

I try to loop inside a array, check if element is not null and ignore duplicates. Looks similar to

```
let tempArr = [];
ARRAY.forEach(element => {
  if(element['sf'] !=null){
    if(tempArr.find(test => test.descripcion != element['sf'])){
    tempArr.push({
    id: element['id'], descripcion: element['sf'] });   
  }
```

But something fails, return empty array.

Somebody know how can i ignore duplicates elements in foreach loop?

Comment: Could you write sample data as text and desired data as text?

Comment: there's a typo in `test.descripcion`, that's one thing .. though that could be colloquialism

Comment: @Ja͢ck I think that's Spanish.

Comment: i think that instead of `if (tempArr.find( ... descripcion != element['sf'])`, it should be `if (!tempArr.find( ... descripcion == element['sf'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this:

```js
const arr = [
 { id: 0, sf: 'a' },  // ok
 { id: 1, sf: null }, // <- no
 { id: 2, sf: 'b' },  // ok
 { id: 3, sf: 'c' },  // ok
 { id: 4, sf: 'c' },  // <- no
 { id: 5, sf: 'd' }   // ok
];

const result = arr.reduce((res, el) => {
  if (el.sf !== null && res.every(x => x.descripcion !== el.sf)) {
    return res.concat({ id: el.id, descripcion: el.sf });
  }
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating your result each time, you can use an intermediate set to keep track of what was inserted, and then use a simple `Array.filter()`

```js
const ARRAY = [
 { id: 1, sf: null },
 { id: 2, sf: 'foo' },
 { id: 3, sf: 'bar' },
 { id: 4, sf: 'foo' }
];

const result = function(data) {
  const seen = new Set()

  return data.filter(item => {
    if (item.sf === null || seen.has(item.sf)) {
      return false;
    }
    seen.add(item.sf)
    return true;
  })
}(ARRAY);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, to combine filter and map operation, you could use `Array.reduce`; the logic that you're after can be generalised to an extent, like so:

```js
// reusable function to filter and map at the same time
function filterMap(array, fn) {
  return array.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const data = fn(o)
    if (data === undefined) {
      return acc; // map function didn't return anything
    }
    acc.push(data);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const result = function(data) {
  const seen = new Set()
  return filterMap(data, item => {
    if (item.sf === null || seen.has(item.sf)) {
      return;
    }
    seen.add(item.sf);
    return {id: item.id, sf: item.sf};
  });
}(ARRAY);
```